# Complex feedback system TIKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hello this is my first TikZ code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning}

\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

\tikzset{
    block/.style = {draw, rectangle,
        minimum height=1cm,
        minimum width=2cm},
    input/.style = {coordinate,node distance=1cm},
    output/.style = {coordinate,node distance=4cm},
    arrow/.style={draw, -latex,node distance=2cm},
    pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={latex-, black,node distance=2cm}},
    sum/.style = {draw, circle, node distance=1cm},
gain/.style = {regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3,
          draw, fill=white, text width=1em,
          inner sep=1mm, outer sep=0mm,
          shape border rotate=-90}
}
\begin{document}


\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=1cm,>=latex']

        %DEFINIZIONE BLOCCHI
        \node [input, name=input] {};
        \node [sum, right=of input] (position_sum) {};
        \node [block, right=of position_sum] (position_controller) {$C_{pos}(s)$};
    \node [sum, right=of position_controller] (speed_sum) {};
        \node [block, right=of speed_sum] (speed_controller) {$C_{vel}(s)$};
    \node [sum, right=of speed_controller] (current_sum) {};
        \node [block, right=of current_sum] (current_controller) {$C_{corr}(s)$};
        \node [block, right=of current_controller] (azionamento) {$Azionamento$};
        \node [gain, right= of azionamento] (Kt) {$K_{t}$};
     \node [sum, right=of Kt, pin={[pinstyle]above:$-C_{R}(s)$},
node distance=3cm] (torque_sum) {};
         \node [block, right=of torque_sum] (system) {$\frac{1}{sJ+f}$};
         \node [block, right=of system] (integrator) {$\frac{1}{s}$};
         \node [gain, right= of integrator] (tau) {$\tau$};
    \node [output, right=of tau] (output) {};
        \node at ($(speed_controller)!0.5!(system)+(0,-2)$) [block] (speed_feedback) {Trasduttore di velocit\`a};

        %DEFINIZIONE COLLEGAMENTI IN CATENA DIRETTA
        \draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$\theta_{M}^{DES}(s)$} (position_sum);
        \draw [->] (position_sum) --  node {$E_{p}(s)$}(position_controller);
        \draw [->] (position_controller) -- node {$\omega_{M}^{DES}(s)$}(speed_sum);
        \draw [->] (speed_sum) -- node {$E_{v}(s)$}(speed_controller);
        \draw [->] (speed_controller) -- node {$I^{DES}(s)$}(current_sum);
          \draw [->] (current_sum) -- (current_controller);
    \draw [->] (current_controller) -- (azionamento);
            \draw [->] (azionamento) -- node  [name=current]{$I(s)$}(Kt);
            \draw [->] (Kt) -- node {$C_{M}(s)$}(torque_sum);
            \draw [->] (torque_sum) -- (system);
     \draw [->] (system) -- node [name=motor_speed] {$s\theta_{M}(s)$}(integrator);
    \draw [->] (integrator) -- node [name=motor_position] {$\theta_{M}(s)$}(tau);
        \draw [->] (tau) -- node [name=tetaload] {$\theta_{C}(s)$}(output);

        %DEFINIZIONE COLLEGAMENTI FEEDBACK
        \draw [->] (current) -- ++ (0,-2) -| node [pos=0.99] {$-$} (current_sum);
        \draw [->] (motor_position) -- ++ (0,-6) -| node [pos=0.99] {$-$} (position_sum);
        \draw [->] (motor_speed)  |- (speed_feedback) ;
        \draw [->] (speed_feedback)  -| node[pos=0.99] {$-$} (speed_sum);
\end{tikzpicture}  

    \caption{Anello di controllo di un asse elettro-meccanico con accoppiamento rigido}
    \label{fig:full_control_loop_rigido}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

The resulting control loop looks like:
[image: Full loop]

So I don't know how to solve the following problems:

1. The image at the top is cut (I can't see the last part of my control loop, exactly the integra, tau and output nodes);
2. The unitary "current feedback" got a superposition with the *Trasduttore di velocità* (speed_feedback);
3. Some variables wrote above the arrows goes in superposition with some blocks;
4. I had to use the `\begin{sidewaysfigure}` since my figure got fully "cut" if i use the `\begin{figure}`.

I am asking for solution of these four problems (or at least 1,2,3) since I am really a newbie with `TikZ`. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your diagram is simply too large for the page. If you tweak the distance between the nodes, reduce the fontsize and `inner sep` of the `gain` nodes, and remove the `minimum width` of the `block` nodes, you can make the rotated version fit in the page at least, though it's still wider than the text area, so you get an `overfull hbox` warning.

An alternative might be to lay it out vertically instead of horizontally, in which case it fits nicely.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning}

\tikzset{
    pinstyle/.style={pin edge={to-,thin,black}},
    block/.style = {draw, rectangle,
        minimum height=1cm,
     %   minimum width=2cm
     },
    input/.style = {coordinate,node distance=1cm},
    output/.style = {coordinate,node distance=4cm},
    arrow/.style={draw, -latex,node distance=2cm},
    pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={latex-, black,node distance=2cm}},
    sum/.style = {draw, circle, node distance=1cm},
gain/.style = {regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3,
          draw, fill=white, text width=1em,
          inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm,
          shape border rotate=-90}
}
\begin{document}


\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=latex',every node/.append style={font=\scriptsize}]

        %DEFINIZIONE BLOCCHI
        \node [input, name=input] {};
        \node [sum, right=of input] (position_sum) {};
        \node [block, right=of position_sum] (position_controller) {$C_{\mathrm{pos}}(s)$};
        \node [sum, right=15mm of position_controller] (speed_sum) {};
        \node [block, right=of speed_sum] (speed_controller) {$C_{\mathrm{vel}}(s)$};
        \node [sum, right=of speed_controller] (current_sum) {};
        \node [block, right=5mm of current_sum] (current_controller) {$C_{\mathrm{corr}}(s)$};
        \node [block, right=5mm of current_controller] (azionamento) {Azionamento};
        \node [gain, right= of azionamento] (Kt) {$K_{t}$};
        \node [sum, right=of Kt, pin={[pinstyle]above:$-C_{R}(s)$},
               node distance=3cm] (torque_sum) {};
        \node [block, right=5mm of torque_sum] (system) {$\frac{1}{sJ+f}$};
        \node [block, right=of system] (integrator) {$\frac{1}{s}$};
        \node [gain, right= of integrator] (tau) {$\tau$};
        \node [output, right=1cm of tau] (output) {};
        \node at ($(speed_controller)!0.5!(system)+(0,-2.5)$) [block] (speed_feedback) {Trasduttore di velocit\`a};

        %DEFINIZIONE COLLEGAMENTI IN CATENA DIRETTA
        \draw [->] (input) -- node {$\theta_{M}^{\mathrm{DES}}(s)$} (position_sum);
        \draw [->] (position_sum) --  node {$E_{p}(s)$}(position_controller);
        \draw [->] (position_controller) -- node {$\omega_{M}^{\mathrm{DES}}(s)$}(speed_sum);
        \draw [->] (speed_sum) -- node {$E_{v}(s)$}(speed_controller);
        \draw [->] (speed_controller) -- node {$I^{\mathrm{DES}}(s)$}(current_sum);
        \draw [->] (current_sum) -- (current_controller);
        \draw [->] (current_controller) -- (azionamento);
        \draw [->] (azionamento) -- node  [name=current]{$I(s)$}(Kt);
        \draw [->] (Kt) -- node {$C_{M}(s)$}(torque_sum);
        \draw [->] (torque_sum) -- (system);
        \draw [->] (system) -- node [name=motor_speed] {$s\theta_{M}(s)$}(integrator);
        \draw [->] (integrator) -- node [name=motor_position] {$\theta_{M}(s)$}(tau);
        \draw [->] (tau) -- node [name=tetaload] {$\theta_{C}(s)$}(output);

        %DEFINIZIONE COLLEGAMENTI FEEDBACK
        \draw [->] (current) -- ++ (0,-1.5) -| node [pos=0.99] {$-$} (current_sum);
        \draw [->] (motor_position) -- ++ (0,-4) -| node [pos=0.99] {$-$} (position_sum);
        \draw [->] (motor_speed)  |- (speed_feedback) ;
        \draw [->] (speed_feedback)  -| node[pos=0.99] {$-$} (speed_sum);
\end{tikzpicture}  

   \caption{Anello di controllo di un asse elettro-meccanico con accoppiamento rigido}
   \label{fig:full_control_loop_rigido}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm, auto,>=latex',every node/.append style={font=\scriptsize},block/.append style={minimum width=2cm}]

        %DEFINIZIONE BLOCCHI
        \node [input, name=input] {};
        \node [sum, below=of input] (position_sum) {};
        \node [block, below=of position_sum] (position_controller) {$C_{\mathrm{pos}}(s)$};
        \node [sum, below=of position_controller] (speed_sum) {};
        \node [block, below=of speed_sum] (speed_controller) {$C_{\mathrm{vel}}(s)$};
        \node [sum, below=of speed_controller] (current_sum) {};
        \node [block, below=of current_sum] (current_controller) {$C_{\mathrm{corr}}(s)$};
        \node [block, below=of current_controller] (azionamento) {Azionamento};
        \node [gain, below= of azionamento] (Kt) {$K_{t}$};
        \node [sum, below=of Kt, pin={[pinstyle]left:$-C_{R}(s)$}] (torque_sum) {};
        \node [block, below=3mm of torque_sum] (system) {$\frac{1}{sJ+f}$};
        \node [block, below=of system] (integrator) {$\frac{1}{s}$};
        \node [gain, below=of integrator] (tau) {$\tau$};
        \node [output, below=1cm of tau] (output) {};
        \node at ($(speed_controller)!0.5!(system)+(4,0)$) [block] (speed_feedback) {Trasduttore di velocit\`a};

        %DEFINIZIONE COLLEGAMENTI IN CATENA DIRETTA
        \draw [->] (input) -- node {$\theta_{M}^{\mathrm{DES}}(s)$} (position_sum);
        \draw [->] (position_sum) --  node {$E_{p}(s)$}(position_controller);
        \draw [->] (position_controller) -- node {$\omega_{M}^{\mathrm{DES}}(s)$}(speed_sum);
        \draw [->] (speed_sum) -- node {$E_{v}(s)$}(speed_controller);
        \draw [->] (speed_controller) -- node {$I^{\mathrm{DES}}(s)$}(current_sum);
        \draw [->] (current_sum) -- (current_controller);
        \draw [->] (current_controller) -- (azionamento);
        \draw [->] (azionamento) -- node  [name=current]{$I(s)$}(Kt);
        \draw [->] (Kt) -- node {$C_{M}(s)$}(torque_sum);
        \draw [->] (torque_sum) -- (system);
        \draw [->] (system) -- node [name=motor_speed] {$s\theta_{M}(s)$}(integrator);
        \draw [->] (integrator) -- node [name=motor_position] {$\theta_{M}(s)$}(tau);
        \draw [->] (tau) -- node [name=tetaload] {$\theta_{C}(s)$}(output);

        %DEFINIZIONE COLLEGAMENTI FEEDBACK
        \draw [->] (current) -- ++ (1.5,0) |- node [pos=0.99] {$-$} (current_sum);
        \draw [->] (motor_position) -- ++ (7,0) |- node [pos=0.99] {$-$} (position_sum);
        \draw [->] (motor_speed)  -| (speed_feedback) ;
        \draw [->] (speed_feedback)  |- node[pos=0.99] {$-$} (speed_sum);
\end{tikzpicture}  

   \caption{Anello di controllo di un asse elettro-meccanico con accoppiamento rigido}
   \label{fig:full_control_loop_rigido}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```